# Basic Partial Fractions

Tags: laplace-transform, partial-fractions

I feel super foolish asking this, but I've reached a mental block.

I'm trying to find the inverse laplace transform of:

$$\frac{s+3}{(s + 1)^2 (s-2)}$$

but, when I expand it into partial fractions:-

$$A(s+1)(s-2) + B(s-2) + C(s+1)^2$$

I get

$$B = -2/3$$
$$C = 5/9$$
$$A = -5/9$$

This is wrong, I've checked on wolfram alpha and it says the answer is

$$\\1/9{}{ e^{-t} (-6 t+5 e^{3t}-5)}$$

Please can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I am puzzled. Is it really $\frac{s+3}{(s+1)^2+(s-2)}$? Then the partial fractions expansion is not correct, the denominator is $s^2+3s-1$. Is there confusion between sum and product?

Comment: yes, sorry, There is no addition sign between the brackets. I've changed the question to reflect this also

Comment: The partial fraction expansion (now that the thing has been corrected) looks right. So now you want to integrate $\frac{A}{s+1}+\frac{B}{(s+1)^2}+\frac{C}{s-2}$.

Comment: But in that case, the result would be -5/9(s + 1) for the first term which would be 5/9e^-t once inverse-laplaced though...which is not what Wolfram Alpha tells us...I'm confused!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partial fraction expansion is:

$$\displaystyle \frac{s+3}{(s-2) (s+1)^2} = -\frac{5}{9(s+1)}-\frac{2}{3(s+1)^2}+ \frac{5}{9(s-2)}$$

The inverse Laplace Transform can now be done for each of those terms. We get:

$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{9} e^{-t} (-6 t+5 e^{3 t}-5)$$

Note that this is a somewhat easier way to display it. Of course, if you want to line things up with the partial fraction fractions, this is identically (just multiply each term in the above expression):

$$\displaystyle -\frac{5}{9} e^{-t} -\frac{2}{3} t e^{-t} + \frac{5}{9} e^{2 t}$$

Do you see it now? I think you may have done everything okay as your constants look correct.

Comment: Ah, ok! it's just me being dumb! Thanks for taking the time to help me out

Comment: @SexySarah: You are very welcome, and trust me, ALL of us have these sort of moments from focusing too intently on problems that we manage to develop blind spots. You are doing excellent and thanks for showing your effort! Regards

Comment: Great feedback, really nice answer! +